# Weight painting "mozzarella effect"

Tags: mesh, bones

I am working on something in unreal engine and I wanted to have a custom character mesh. I downloaded a mesh then imported the ue4 skeleton in blender, deleted the mesh (just kept the bones) and imported my downloaded mesh.

The UE4 skeleton and my mesh did not have quite the same pose so I had to move some bones around to make them fit the new mesh. Once this was done I wanted to parent and weight the mesh so it could be animated.

The automatic weighting did not work. I tried to do some research and it seems one problem could be that all the bones are not inside the mesh, but I think they all are. Another thing could be that my mesh is not "Closed". I could not get it to work so I decided to try to paint weights myself.

I did painted the whole upper body, but when I tried to move a spine bone in pose mode, there was some kind of "Cheese string" effect. I cant describe it better but the video shows it. I'm worried the weight paint didnt got applied everywhere, I'm not sure if it is a problem with my mesh. If anyone can help that would be great, thanks.
[video showing the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9fA5MvayHA)

I've shared two files. The one named "Works" is another try I just did. It seems the mesh is simpler and it looks "Closed" so I guess that is the problem with the other one.

Quick note: I don't own the two meshes

[image] 
[image]

The problem is not the head not moving, I haven't weight painted it yet. The problem like in the hands, there ares points that seem to not move, then it stretches the mesh. Same for the shoulder. This is a screenshot of the lower arm weight paint. I've outlined a little area that is not getting painted, I'm afraid the problem comes from that and I don't know how to solve it. [image: image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/50/4/1607633243-capture.jpg]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi, i've just shared two files. The one named "works" is another try i just did. It seems the mesh is simpler and it looks "closed" so i guess that is the problem with the other one.
Quick note: i don't own the two meshes
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=NvPSYZsx" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/NvPSYZsx/)
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=SBYMO03r" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/SBYMO03r/)

Comment: Please place a screen Blender capture in your question.  Please also show the your model in weight paint mode for the largest defect bone.

Comment: Do you think it is a problem that the back is moving and the head stay in place?  If you do not like your weight painting I suggest you start again with a fresh start.  It seems you have already identified the problem.

Comment: As it is made you can't animate this kind of armature by yourself, so I guess you need to import and assign actions. As for the weight, you need to give it corrections, but for example the character is not in T pose, you need to correct that.

Comment: No the head is fine, i haven't weight painted it yet. the problem like in the hands, there ares points that seem to not move, then it stretches the mech. Same for the shoulder.
This is a screenshot of the lower arm weight paint. I've outlined a little area that is not getting painted, i'm affraid the problem comes from that and i don't know hoe to solve it. https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/50/4/1607633243-capture.jpg

Comment: Please place all new information in your question as an [edit] so that users can see it there. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many approaches to solve this kind of problems.

Some of them:

- In edit mode select the vertices you need and "assign" weight instead of painting.
  [image]
- In edit mode press P and separate some parts into a new object, weight paint the new object, then rejoin (Ctrl J): the weights will remain intact.
- In weight paint mode use Alt B to isolate the zone you want to paint and change the tools behaviour, unclicking the "front faces only" button and selecting the "projected" falloff shape, so that every vertex under the cursor (in a 2D fashion) will get painted.
  [image]

Comment: Man you are a savior! I just tested all of your three solutions and they all work like a charm. I'll play around a bit more with them to get familiar and then i'll be able to continue my project. Thank you a lot Sir!

Comment: maybe you could also mention vertex/face paint, then you have one more useful method ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to separate the limbs from the main body to make the painting easier. I used the third solution you gave with disabling "front face only" on the brush. I still have a problem tho and it is kind of similar to my first one. Some vertices seem to not be taken into account by the weight painting. Moreover, it seem to be the ones i worked on when separating the limbs from the body (around the shoulder and the neck).
[image: The body here is rotates 90° on its back and some vertices are staying where the shoulders where and making those lines]

The body here is rotates 90° on its back and some vertices are staying were the shoulders where and making those lines.
I have no idea if i did something wrong while manipulating the vertices.
Here is my file: [image]

Comment: I just reimported the model and redid the separation and it worked this time. i probably did something wrong the last time.