# Weight paint attached objects

Tags: weight-painting

Hi I like to know how to weight paint the whole attached object on a single bone without separating it from the mesh. For example, I want to paint the whole flower to a bone without affecting the mesh behind. In Maya you have the option to select the vertices that you want in edit mode and assign them to a bone, but I cant find anything like that in blender. Can someone help me please?  [image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204791/weight-painting-mozzarella-effect/204840#204840

Answer (score 4):

in edit mode, just select the faces/vertices, you want to paint on

[image]

in weight paint mode, just click here:

[image]

then it only paints what you selected

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually I just select the verts and then adjust their influence in the vertex groups panel, but like Chris said, masking is a good way to keep the ability to paint.

[image: vertex panel]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).